# Admob hide ads and stop refreshing

Tags: admob, hide, adview, impressions

What is the best way to hide adMob ads and stop refreshing them? to keep ad impressions (so it won't affect negatively the ad revenue) also the network usage and overall performance.
Android Adview docs don't say much, it's enough doing something like this?

```
case SHOW_ADS:
{
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
}
case HIDE_ADS:
{
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    break;
}
```

adView stop fetching ads when is not visible? or it's needed

```
case SHOW_ADS:
{
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adView.resume();
    break;
}
case HIDE_ADS:
{
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adView.pause();
    break;
}
```

Comment: How did you get on with this @zappp?  I'm having a very similar issue....., I don't seem to be able to use either method reliably as there are problem with both......(although I'm using the MobFox SDK, not the AdMob SDK).

Comment: With the AdMob SDK was sufficient to use setVisibility(View.GONE) adView method, I figured watching LogCat that ads stop refreshing when hidden I also used this method setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) otherwise I get a blackbox in the ad place for some reason.

Comment: Aha, I see. You're lucky, because with the MobFox SDK, even with setVisibility(View.GONE); Ads still seem to get served! I may have switch back. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

can't hide because admob compulsorily put this code to our manifest.xml file so they can know it is tablet or mobile etc

```
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```